# Facebook OAuth Dialog not showing app description

Tags: dialog, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

My site uses Facebook Login to retrieve user information for form submission.

The permissions dialog stemming from FB.login() does not show the "About this App" section... is there any way to get more information in this dialog? I noticed the preview your Login Dialog on the App dashboard under settings/permissions was recently removed.

Any information how I can achieve the same goal but have the about portion on my oauth dialog would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid clutter, there's currently no way to get your app's description shown in the dialog.

Instead, you should present the value proposition at the point where the user is prompted to click 'Log in', 'use app' etc, so that when they get to the oauth dialog, they are comfortable with granting the requested permissions.

Comment: Do you know if FB plans to add this to the oAuth Dialog?